# How to make a questionnaire scrollable in Python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I am new to Python and have been working on a school project. The idea is to take the Alcohol Use Disorders Identification Test (AUDIT) and let the user know whether or not he should seek professional help (if he scores 14+). 
I got stuck today. I'm using tkinter, and a set of 10 questions with radioboxes. However, I can't proceed since the questions do not fit on the screen and for the love of God I can't make it scrollable. I've tried everything I could find, setting a class,  trying to work with a frame or a canvas, etc.
The questions look like this:

```
"""imports"""
import tkinter as tk
app = tk.Tk()
app.title("AUDIT")
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

canvas = tk.Canvas(app)
scroll_y = tk.Scrollbar(app, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)

frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
# group of widgets
"""question 1"""
o1 = Text(app, height = 1, width =100)
o1.insert(INSERT, "Jak často pijete alkoholické nápoje (včetně piva)")
o1.insert(END, "?")
o1.pack()
OTAZKA1 = [
        ("Nikdy", "0"),
        ("Jednou za měsíc či méně často", "1"),
        ("2-4x za měsíc", "2"),
        ("2-3x týdně", "3"),
        ("4x nebo vícekrát týdně", "4"),
        ]
o1 = StringVar()
o1.set("0") #initialize

for text, mode in OTAZKA1:
    a = Radiobutton(app, text = text, variable = o1, value = mode)
    a.pack(anchor=W)

"""question 2"""
o2 = Text(app, height = 2, width =100)
o2.insert(INSERT, "Kolik standardních sklenic alkoholického nápoje vypijete během typického dne, kdy pijete")
o2.insert(END, "?")
o2.pack()
OTAZKA2 = [
        ("Nejvýše 1", "0"),
        ("1,5 až 2", "1"),
        ("2,5 až 3", "2"),
        ("3,5 až 5", "3"),
        ("5 a více", "4"),
        ]
o2 = StringVar()
o2.set("0") #initialize

for text, mode in OTAZKA2:
    b = Radiobutton(app, text = text, variable = o2, value = mode)
    b.pack(anchor=W)
```

All the way up to question 10. I know this may not the the most efficient way but it's the first code I've ever written.
How can I add the scroll bar to make all of the questions visible?
Thank you, have a great day.

Comment: To make it scrollable, you can use a Canvas widget. And create the questionnaire entries with Canvas.create_window(x, y, window=entry_frame) method

Comment: PS: you may also use Label widgets instead of the Text widgets (for questions).

Comment: And by the way, you may generate the widgets automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1) use `Canvas.create_window(x, y, window=widget)` method

2) set the canvas `scrollregion` attribute to `Canvas.bbox("all")` (but before you must update the window, otherwise you'll get the wrong result"

3) attach the scrollbar to the canvas the right way (see the code below)

I can also give you some advice:

1) It's better to use OOP for the GUI. For the small apps, it may not be the problem, but if your app is more complex and big, you'll be much easier to work with the OOP code, than with the procedural one.

2) Did you notice your code has a lot of similar parts? Remember: in almost all cases, there is no need to create a lot of similar variables manually (it's also called the [DRY principle (don't repeat yourself)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). You may generate everything automatically using loops. Sometimes you need to use the [`enumerate`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumerate-in-python/) function from Python built-ins. If you won't use the DRY principle, you will spend much more time for the development. 

3) It's better to avoid overriding already imported things by importing another module. In your code, you do:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
```

**Both** of these modules contain `Button`, `Entry`, `Scrollbar`, `Radiobutton` etc. So you may get everything mixed up. It's better to do like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import only, what, you, need
```

or even better:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk  # or: from tkinter import ttk
```

4) You may adjust the size of everything in Canvas manually, and deny resizing of the window (either by width and/or height).

Here is the rewritten code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.ttk import Button, Scrollbar, Radiobutton


# Create questions as a list of dictionaries
# The GUI will be generated automatically
questions = [
    {"question": "Jak často pijete alkoholické nápoje (včetně piva)?",
     "answers": ("Nikdy", "Jednou za měsíc či méně často",
                 "2-4x za měsíc", "2-3x týdně",
                 "4x nebo vícekrát týdně")},
    {"question": "Kolik standardních sklenic alkoholického nápoje vypijete během typického dne, kdy pijete?",
    "answers": ("Nejvýše 1", "1,5 až 2", "2,5 až 3", "3,5 až 5", "5 a více")},
    ]

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("AUDIT")  # set the window title
        self.resizable(False, True)  # make window unresizable by width

        canv_frame = Frame(self)  # create the canvas frame
        # create the Canvas widget
        # highlightthickness=0 removes the black border when the canvas gets focus
        self.canv = Canvas(canv_frame, highlightthickness=0, width=420)
        # add scrolling when mouse wheel is rotated
        self.canv.bind_all("<MouseWheel>",
                           lambda event: self.canv.yview_scroll(-1 * (event.delta // 120), "units"))
        self.canv.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES, side=LEFT)  # pack the Canvas

        # Create a scrollbar
        # command=self.canv.yview tells the scrollbar to change the canvas yview
        # and canvas's yscrollcommand=self.yscrollbar.set tells the canvas to update
        # the scrollbar if canvas's yview is changed without it.
        self.yscrollbar = Scrollbar(canv_frame, command=self.canv.yview)
        self.canv["yscrollcommand"] = self.yscrollbar.set
        self.yscrollbar.pack(fill=Y, side=LEFT)  # pack the Scrollbar

        for question_id, question in enumerate(questions, 1):
            qaframe = Frame(self.canv)  # create the question-answers (QA) frame
            text = Text(qaframe, width=50, height=3)  # create the Text widget for question
            text.insert(END, question["question"])  # insert the question text there
            text.pack(fill=X)  # pack the text widget
            aframe = Frame(qaframe)  # create the answers frame
            # Create the question variable and add it to the variables list
            question_var = IntVar(self)
            question["variable"] = question_var
            # create the radiobuttons 
            for answer_id, answer in enumerate(question["answers"]):
                Radiobutton(aframe, variable=question_var, text=answer, value=answer_id).pack()
            aframe.pack(fill=Y)  # pack the answers frame
            self.canv.create_window(210, question_id * 175, window=qaframe)  # insert the QA frame into the Canvas
        canv_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)  # pack the canvas frame
        Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.submit).pack(fill=X)  # create the "Submit" button
        self.update()  # update everything to get the right scrollregion.
        self.canv.configure(scrollregion=self.canv.bbox("all"))  # set the canvas scrollregion

    def submit(self):
        sum_ = 0  # initially, the sum_ equals 0
        for question in questions:
            sum_ += question["variable"].get()  # and then, we add all the questions answers
        messagebox.showinfo("Result", "Your result is %s!" % sum_)  # show the result in an info messagebox

if __name__ == "__main__":  # if the App is not imported from another module,
    App().mainloop()  # create it and start the mainloop
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the advice. You are absolutely right and I did not think of that! I will try to finish the project and change the code accordingly. Have a great day.

Comment: @AemiliaUrban Thanks. I'm glad if I could help. Have a nice day!